# How to skin an ASP.NET GridView column?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, skin

The idea is simple - I want all Command columns in my GridViews to have a specific button image for, say, the "Delete" button. Sounds like a job for skins, but I cannot find the right syntax for that...

Comment: A really interesting question. I hope you found an answer to it.

Comment: @AshrafSabry - Yeah, we moved over to DevExpress. :D (Although we're considering moving away from it again)

Comment: My company uses Telerik's RadGrid, and I don't like it too.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to template the GridView and add an image button to me. here is a link:
http://andybrudtkuhl.wordpress.com/2006/06/12/gridview-with-an-imagebutton/

Comment: Well, uh, no. There is already a CommandField there which does exactly this with way less code. Of course, the ImageButton in your template could be set a SkinID which would solve the problem in a way... but IMHO that's kind of re-inveinting the wheel. I was hoping for something more elegant.